# Lazy loading in Gridview using jquery and webmethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, web, webmethod

How to use lazy loading in gridview by binding datatable to gridview using webmethod and jquery. A Gridview contain more than million records. Lazy loading is depend upon gridview scrolling.

Comment: [Here is the Article](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Loading-data-in-GridView-while-scrolling-down-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article is helpful for lazy loading in gridview.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-on-demand-data-in-GridView-on-scroll-using-ASPNet-and-jQuery-AJAX.aspx